# How can I integrate a Shiny Server in a J2EE application?

Tags: node.js, jakarta-ee, shiny, shiny-server

I'm developing a Java EE application (Spring + MongoDB + AngularJS) and now I need to integrate Shiny Server with that. For what I know, Shiny is a Node.js application. Is there a proper way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Well, for now I've followed the same technique I've found in Shiny's website:

http://shiny.rstudio.com/

Right there, in the main page, they have an embedded Shiny app. And it's an old-fashioned iframe.

So that's what I've used, **iframes to embed Shiny apps** into my own application. That is not the best solution, probably, but it's one that gets the job done as long as you don't require further interaction with it.